# Symfony3 Impossible to access an attribute ("small_pizza") on a string variable ("Margherita")

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I trying to display price, but occurs error Impossible to access an attribute ("small_pizza") on a string variable ("Margherita").

This is my Controller:

```
/**
     * @Route(
     *      "/menu",
     *      name = "pizza_menu"
     * )
     * 
     * @Template
     */
    public function menuAction() {

        $Repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('PizzaBundle:Menu');
        $rows = $Repo->findAll();

        return array(
            'rows' => $rows
        );
    }
```

And this is my database:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjY22.png)

In a Twig code is this:

```
{% for entry in rows %}
   <tr>
      <td>{{ entry.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ entry.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ entry.components }}</td>
      <td>
          <ul>
              <li>{{ entry.name.small_pizza }}</li>
              <li>{{ entry.name.small_pizza }}</li>
              <li>{{ entry.name.small_pizza }}</li>
              <li>{{ entry.name.small_pizza }}</li>

          </ul>
      </td>
  </tr>
```

Help me please :)

Comment: The kind of question that makes me hungry :)

Comment: hehehe :) yes, of course :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try accessing to the prince entity navigating the relations so try this:

```
<li>{{ entry.price.small_pizza }}</li>
```

instead of

```
<li>{{ entry.name.small_pizza }}</li>
```

Hope this help

Comment: I did your way, but I get a this error :(

Neither the property "small_pizza" nor one of the methods "small_pizza()", "getsmall_pizza()"/"issmall_pizza()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection".

Comment: @artro8 probably I miss the schema relation, so a menu row have a oneToMany relation with price, so one pizza can have many price, is correct? Otherwise post your entity class (with the relations)

Comment: This is my entites is down on this page

Comment: My problem was in relation. I must used to ManyToMany and change name in twig on the "smallPizza''. Thank you Matteo with your time.